# dynamic cast of a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have a few classes of which I've made std::shared_ptr versions, as follows:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<MediaItem> MediaItemPtr;
typedef std::shared_ptr<ImageMediaItem> ImageMediaItemPtr;

class MediaItem
{
   //stuff here
}

class ImageMediaItem : public MediaItem
{
   //more stuff here
}
```

Internally, I pass everything around as a MediaItemPtr object, but when I try to cast to a ImageMediaItemPtr, nothing I try seems to work. For example:

```
ImageMediaItemPtr item = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<ImageMediaItemPtr>(theItem);
//theItem is MediaItemPtr
```

Fails with

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from
>   'std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty>' to 'std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty>'

Any thoughts of how this cast should actually work? I'm a bit new to shared_ptr

Answer (score 11):

The template argument to `dynamic_pointer_cast` should be the pointed-to type. In other words, it should be `T` and not `shared_ptr<T>`.

In this case, it should be `dynamic_pointer_cast<ImageMediaItem>` and not `dynamic_pointer_cast<ImageMediaItemPtr>`.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/IQHPOL
I'm trying your solution and it doesn't seem to work. What am I missing here?

Comment: @arunmoezhi As the error message says, "the operand of a runtime dynamic_cast must have a polymorphic class type", i.e. your class needs to have a virtual function.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
ImageMediaItemPtr item = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<ImageMediaItem>(theItem);
```