# How do I cast a shared_ptr from one parent class to another parent class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I am in the process of re-working my game engine to use `smart-pointers`. I have an `Object` class which everything inherits from. I have a GameObject which is renderable so it inherits from `IRenderable` (a class that defines a pure virtual render function) and **does not inherit from Object**. I have a `RenderSystem` which is supposed to hold a `shared_ptr` to all IRenderable in the scene.

The problem that I have is how do I cast my GameObject shared_ptr to an IRenderable for the RenderSystem?

Ideas that I have tried:

- RenderSystem uses shared_ptr of GameObject but this doesn't work as it is dangerous because not all gameObjects are renderable.
- Have IRenderable inherit from Object which should allow for me to inherit from it. This would mean that IRenderable is no longer an interface as Object has other functions included.

This is completely do-able with raw pointers and as such, I feel like there is some way to achieve the same result with smart pointers

Example:

```
// Object.h
class Object : public enable_shared_from_this<Object> { ... }
// GameObject.h
class GameObject : public Object { ... }
// MeshRenderer.h
class MeshRenderer : public GameObject, IRenderable { 
public:
    void initialize()
    {
         // Not able to cast Object to IRenderable
         RenderSystem::instance().addRenderable(getShared());

         // AND

         // Not able to cast Object to IRenderable

RenderSystem::instance().addRenderable(std::static_pointer_cast<IRenderable>(getShared()));
    }
}
// RenderSystem.h
class RenderSystem 
{
    std::list<std::shared_ptr<IRenderable>> m_renderables;
 public:
    void addRenderable(std::shared_ptr<IRenderable> ptr)
    {
       m_renderables.push_back(ptr);
    }
}

// main.cpp
...
auto meshRenderer = std::shared_ptr<MeshRenderer>();
...
```

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/20219385/103167 ?   See if `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: I will try that right now.

Comment: Note that shared_ptr is heavy and slow. In real applications it is used mostly in places where performance does not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
#include <memory>

// everything is an Object - yuk, but ok, if you wish...
struct Object : std::enable_shared_from_this<Object>
{
};

struct GameObject : Object
{

};

struct IRenderable
{
    virtual void render() {};
};

struct RederableGameObject : GameObject, IRenderable
{
    auto as_shared_renderable() -> std::shared_ptr<IRenderable>
    {
        // builds a new shared pointer to IRenderable which
        // uses the same lifetime control block as me
        return std::shared_ptr<IRenderable>
        {
            this->shared_from_this(),   // where to get the control block
            this                        // what to point to
        };
    }
};
```

Documentation:

See constructor number (8)

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr

Update:

Here is a starting point for a free function to fetch a correct shared_pointer from any object provided it is ultimately publicly derived from `std::enable_shared_from_this`

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

namespace notstd
{
    // stuff that I think *should be* std

    using namespace std;

    // a trait to determine whether class T is derived from template
    // Tmpl<...>

    template <typename T, template <class...> class Tmpl>
    struct is_derived_from_template_impl
    {
        static std::false_type test(...);

        template <typename...Us>
        static std::true_type test(Tmpl<Us...> const &);

        using result = decltype(test(std::declval<T>()));
    };

    template <typename T, template <class...> class Tmpl>
    using is_derived_from_template = typename is_derived_from_template_impl<T, Tmpl>::result;

    template <typename T, template <class...> class Tmpl>
    constexpr auto is_derived_from_template_v = is_derived_from_template<T, Tmpl>::value;


    // free function version of shared_from_this

    template<class T> 
    auto shared_from(enable_shared_from_this<T>* p) 
    -> std::shared_ptr<T>
    {
        return p->shared_from_this();
    }

    // specific shared_ptr construction from type T

    template<class T> 
    auto shared_from(T*p) 
    -> enable_if_t
    <
        is_derived_from_template_v
        <
            T, 
            enable_shared_from_this
        >, 
        std::shared_ptr<T>
    >
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<T>(p->shared_from_this(), p);
    }

}

// everything is an Object - yuk, but ok, if you wish...
struct Object : std::enable_shared_from_this<Object>
{
};

struct GameObject : Object
{

};

struct IRenderable
{
    virtual void render() {};
};

extern int emit(const char* str);

struct RederableGameObject : GameObject, IRenderable
{
    auto as_shared_renderable() -> std::shared_ptr<RederableGameObject>
    {
        return notstd::shared_from(this);
    }

    auto as_shared_renderable() const -> std::shared_ptr<const RederableGameObject>
    {
        return notstd::shared_from(this);
    }

    void e() const {
        emit("const");
    }
    void e()  {
        emit("mutable");
    }


};



int main()
{

    auto rgo = std::make_shared<RederableGameObject>();

    // prove it works
    auto p1 = rgo->as_shared_renderable();

    // prove it works with a const object also
    auto p2 = static_cast<const RederableGameObject&>(*rgo).as_shared_renderable();

    p1->e();
    p2->e();
}
```

Comment: `return std::static_pointer_cast<RenderableGameObject>(shared_from_this());` would work too. Downcast to the type of `*this` and then allow an implicit upcast to the other base type.

Comment: @JonathanWakely agreed. But felt the question was better answered explicitly. In fact in my own code I use a free template function `template<class T> std::shared_ptr<T> shared_from(T* self)`, with appropriate enable-iffing to ensure no conversion if T is directly derived from `std::enable_shared_from_this`. It's a shame something like that is not in the standard.

Comment: @RichardHodges do you mind adding the template version? as I might need to perform the same function in other classes down the line.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do a `static_pointer_cast` directly from `shared_ptr<Object>` to `shared_ptr<IRenderable>` because those types are unrelated.

But you can cast to the derived type, then allow an implicit conversion to `shared_ptr<IRenderable>`:

```
auto p = std::static_pointer_cast<MeshRenderer>(getShared());
std::shared_ptr<IRenderer> q = p;
```

This performs an explicit conversion from the first base class to the derived type, then an implicit conversion to the second base type. This is statically allowed, because the derived type is known to be related to both bases, but a direct conversion between the unrelated bases isn't possible.